# How can I change the tabs event on different screen size?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

For Desktop I want them to act on hover, on mobile, obviously on click event.

For desktop I have this:

```
$('#cards-tabs').tabs({
    event: 'mouseover'
});
```

But what can I do to adapt the event `event: 'click'` instead when mobile screen comes?

Answer (score 0):

You could have the javascript check the screenwidth for when the mobile layout is expected to be shown, and change the event based on that. Though this doesn't show the code for getting `screenWidth`, an example of this approach might look like:

```
$('#cards-tabs').tabs({
    event: ( screenWidth <= 420 ? 'click' : 'mouseover')
});
```

Or, another option would be to have the styles hide the desktop tabs when on mobile, and to show different tabs that already have the `click` event always bound to them.

Though, I think the first solution would be better.